# vhost ip filter express node

Tags: node.js, express, express-vhost

I'm using `vhost` with `express` to manage two subdomain. All work well but I would like to filter the request for one of the subdomain by ip. Do you know if it's possible to do ?

I've tried to manage it in the app.js of my subdomain site but the `req.connection.remoteAddress` and `req.ip` give me the ip of my server.

When I've got only one subdomain and don't use vhost I've got the right ip, but since I used vhost I've got the ip of my server ...

Here is my folder structure before :

```
-- subdomain1/
    -- app.js
    -- views/
```

Here is my new structure :

```
-- subdomain1/
    -- app.js
    -- views/
-- subdomain2/
    -- app.js
    -- views/
-- manageSubdomain/
    -- app.js
```

Here is my code when it work before using vhost and for only one subdomain :

subdomain1/app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('body-parser-xml')(bodyParser);

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Example middleware to get ip
app.use(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.ip); // it give me the correct IP
});

app.use('/', routes);

module.exports = app;
```

And the file who manage the server before :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('webservicePrestashop:server');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '443');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

//var server = http.createServer(app);
var options = {
     key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/privkey.pem'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/fullchain.pem'),
     ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/chain.pem')
}
var server = https.createServer(options, app);

// Redirect from http port 80 to https
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url });
    res.end();
}).listen(80);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Here is my code to manage subdomain :

manageSubdomain/app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var vhost = require('vhost');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var tls = require('tls');

// Gestions des sites
const subdomain1 = {
    app: require('../subdomain1/app'),
    context: tls.createSecureContext({
        key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/privkey.pem').toString(),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/privkey.pem/fullchain.pem').toString(),
        ca: fs.readFileSync('path/to/privkey.pem/chain.pem').toString()
    }).context
};
const subdomain2 = {
    app: require('../subdomain2/app'),
    context: tls.createSecureContext({
        key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/privkey.pem/privkey.pem').toString(),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/privkey.pem/fullchain.pem').toString(),
        ca: fs.readFileSync('path/to/privkey.pem/chain.pem').toString()
    }).context
};
var sites = {
    "my.subdomain1.com": subdomain1,
    "my.subdomain2.com": subdomain2
};

var exp = express();
for (let s in sites) {
  exp.use(vhost(s, sites[s].app));
}

// Redirect du http to https
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url });
    res.end();
}).listen(80);

var secureOpts = {
    SNICallback: function (domain, cb) {
        if (typeof sites[domain] === "undefined") {
            cb(new Error("domain not found"), null);
            console.log("Error: domain not found: " + domain);
        } else {
            cb(null, sites[domain].context);
        }
    },
    key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/privkey.pem/privkey.pem').toString(),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/privkey.pem/fullchain.pem').toString()
};

// Création du serveur https
var httpsServer = https.createServer(secureOpts, exp);
httpsServer.listen(443);
```

Now my subdomain1/app.js is the same than before

Comment: Could you add the initial working code (without vhost) and the minimum not working code with vhost? Please add also a log statement for request host/ip address.

Comment: I edit with all the possible code, hope it help you. I've no log to show you, only the difference of ip but not sure it will help you. Thanks a lot

Comment: Try adding the logging middleware as in my updated answer.

Comment: Both give me the ip of the server

Comment: Now, if I use the old server file i've got the correct IP but when I use the new file, I've got the server IP

Comment: Are you running both apps in the same environment? Could you try mounting the two subapps directly without vhost just to check if something change? From what you've done so far, seems that the problem isn't vhost, because the middleware before it's use, return the wrong ip address...

Comment: Yeah i'm using the same environment. If I mount only one subdomain without vhost, I get the correct ip but I can't do it without vhost. Yeah, it's strange ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150982/discussion-between-lifeisfoo-and-jean-max).

Comment: What about directly using `X-Forwarded-For` header value?

Comment: Same result, I'v got the ip of the server

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the [`req.ip`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.ip) property?

Express documentation says:

> Contains the remote IP address of the request.
>
> When the trust proxy setting does not evaluate to false, the value of
>   this property is derived from the left-most entry in the
>   X-Forwarded-For header. This header can be set by the client or by the
>   proxy.

To debug your code, add a logging middleware *before* adding any app to the express object:

```
var exp = express();

// ip logging middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.ip);
    next();
});

for (let s in sites) {
  exp.use(vhost(s, sites[s].app));
}
```

Then, add the same middleware as the first middleware of your sub apps. In this way you can be sure that the problem is caused by the `vhost` module.

Comment: Yes, but it give me the same result : ip of my server

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy in front of your express app: apache, nginx, haproxy...?

Comment: No, only node and express